# Se elimina la Tabla temporal usando la misma sesión usando Mariadb

Tags: c#, mariadb, odbc

Mi proyecto esta bajo el lenguaje de c#, utilizo el odbc connector de mariadb para poder conectarme a mi servidor de las cuales el conection string es el siguiente :

```
DRIVER={" + Driverodbc + "};SERVER=xxxx;PORT=xxxx;DATABASE=xxxx;UID = xxxx;PASSWORD=xxxx;OPTION=67108864;CONN_TIMEOUT=150000;INTERACTIVE=true;AUTO_RECONNECT=true;"
```

De acuerdo con la documentación de [MARIADB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/) Al crear una tabla temporal, esta se borrará cuando la sesión actual se termine Cito texto:

> Temporary tables are dropped when the session ends.

El **problema** es que la tabla se me *borra al realizar una nueva consulta* utilizando la misma **conexion**

Las consultas estan almacenadas en un DATATABLE llamado sql, que el primer campo es un string, De esta consulto uno a uno las consultas y las ejecuto, mostrado en el codigo siguiente:

```
private OdbcConnection conexion;
OdbcTransaction transaccionmysql;
conexion.Connect();
                    transaccionmysql = conexion.BeginTransaction();
                    try
                    {

                        foreach (DataRow consulta in Sql.Rows)
                        {
                            using (var query2 = new OdbcCommand(consulta["sql"].ToString(), conexion))
                            {
                                query2.Transaction = transaccionmysql;
                                

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(consulta["sql"].ToString()))
                                {
                                    
                                    query2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }

                                query2.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
```

Evito mostrar el manejo de los parámetros porque funcionan  correctamente
El código que utilizo para crear la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
Sql.Rows.Add("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE indicesaimportar SELECT TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SEQ_IN_INDEX, COLUMN_NAME, (CASE WHEN NON_UNIQUE = 0 THEN 'UNIQUE' WHEN INDEX_TYPE = 'FULLTEXT' THEN 'FULLTEXT' ELSE '' END) AS 'INDEX_TYPE' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='';");
Sql.Rows.Add("ALTER TABLE indicesaimportar ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;");
```

El error que me reporta el conector ODBC es el siguiente

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [42S02]
> [ma-3.1.11][10.5.8-MariaDB-log]Tabla 'nueva.indicesaimportar' no
> existe'

Comment: ¿¡Comentario fuera de la pregunta, pero bueno, de los que leen la pregunta, un feedback solicitaría!, les parece mal formulada? ¿No conocen del tema? ¡Quiero mejorar mi manera de expresar y bueno quisiera saber si voy bien! Gracias

Comment: No estoy seguro si la instrucción `query2.Dispose();` cierra la conexión, según [Creation of temporary tables with multiple statements in one query fails.](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-159) debería poder acceder a la tabla temporal.